# How to set attributes without overriding the Mahapps theme?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, microsoft-metro, resourcedictionary

I'm using Mahapps for a GUI, however I want to set some attributes different than visual ones such as `margins` and `verticalAlignment`, so I added this to the `UserControl.resources` section

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type TextBox}}">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

However it overrides all the visual styles attributes of the TextBoxes, how can I just add those attributes without overriding all the visual styles settings?

Comment: It will affect all the `TextBox` for the simple reason that the `Key` defined by you is targeting all `TextBox` in general. Instead give the `Key` a normal name like `Key="SpecificTextBox"`. Then just point to this style in your xaml definition for the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the style a key

```
<Style x:Key="myCustomTextBoxStyle"
       TargetType="TextBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type TextBox}}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

and use it where you need it

```
<TextBox Style={StaticResource myCustomTextBoxStyle} />
```

**EDIT**
or put it to the main resource dictionary of user control or window resource without a key

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type TextBox}}">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I want to avoid setting styles for each component I use

Comment: @user2005494 you can make the style without a key and put it to main resource dictionary where your controls are hosted